# Can a script remove the folder in which is contained? + PBS job

Tags: rm, pbs

I have a bash script which does some operations and at the end I would like the script to delete the folder in which it is contained.
So I put at the end of the script the following commands

```
olddir=`pwd`
cd ..
rm -rf "$olddir"
```

The content of the folder is deleted, but the folder not and I get the following error

```
rm: cannot remove `folder': Directory not empty
```

The script is called by a pbs script which is also contained in the same folder.
What is the problem?

Comment: `rm -rf` calls `rmdir()` function internally after removing all the files in the directory. If some other process created new file in the direcrory while `rm -rf` was running it would fail like that. See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12616/17649

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to clean up a directory that the job is going to use, the best thing to do would probably be to create a specific directory at the beginning of the job instead of simply backing up and deleting the current directory as you are currently doing.

I think you'd be better off doing something like:

1. Make a directory
2. Set the permissions so only you can access it.
3. cd to that directory
4. do all the work for your job
5. cd back to the original working directory
6. remove the created directory.